# Repeat checkbox not working on Global Actions quick action layout for event

Tags: page-layout, event, bug, quickaction, global-actions

When on the calendar tab or event object directly checking the repeat checkbox expands another menu allowing the user to choose the repeat interval.  However, when creating an event from an associated object -- this does not happen and it throws an error.  The attached layout is controlled from global actions whereas for the object it is controlled from the page layout itself.

[image: When on the calendar tab or event object directly checking the repeat checkbox expands another menu allowing the user to choose the repeat interval. However, when creating an event from an associated object -- this does not happen and it throws an error. The attached layout is controlled from global actions whereas for the object it is controlled from the page layout itself.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though repeat is generally available after spring 19 release, as of now you can not use it in Quick action. Read more here:- [Event series aren’t supported for quick actions.](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=creating_events_lex.htm&type=5)

As a Workaround, To create an event directly from object record with repeat functionality, You can add related list single standard component with related list name as Open Activities in your record lightning page via lightning app builder.

It has other advantages also as if you are using record types for event and task, you can select record type before creating it as well as repeat will work fine.

Read more here:- [Open Activities and Activity History Related List in Lightning Experience](https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/02/04/open-activities-and-activity-history-related-list-in-lightning-experience/)

[image]

if you click on the new event then below popup will appears:-

[image]